# C#. How to excecute a query on recordset?

Tags: c#

HI,

I am trying to convert the following vba code to c# and i am facing some errors.Hope someone can help me

vba code

```
    Open "C:\testfile.txt" For Input As #1
        varii = ""
        Do While Not EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, strField
        varii = varii & "," & strField
        Loop
        Close #1
        astrFields = Split(varii, ",")

    For intIx = 1 To UBound(astrFields)
    counter = 0
    i = i + 1

    Dim cn As New ADODB.Connection, cn2 As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim connString As String
    Dim SelectFieldName
    Set cn = CurrentProject.Connection
    SelectFieldName = astrFields(intIx)
    Set rs = cn.OpenSchema(adSchemaColumns, _
    Array(Empty, Empty, Empty, SelectFieldName))

        If Left(rs!Table_Name, 4) <> "MSys" And Left(rs!Table_Name, 4) <> "Abfr
    " Then

strSql = "SELECT t.[" & astrFields(intIx) & "], t.fall from [" & rs!Tab
    le_Name & "] t Inner Join 01UMWELT on t.fall = [01UMWELT].fall "
            End If
    Set rs3 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSql)
    Do While Not rs3.EOF
    With rs3
    feedbackmsg = "Processing " & rs!Table_Name & " Record no : "
    & .Fields(1)
    SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, feedbackmsg
    varii = Nz(.Fields(astrFields(intIx)), "NullValue")
    If varii = "NullValue" Then
    Call .Edit
    .Fields(astrFields(intIx)) = 888
    Call .Update
```

THis is the c# code so far i have coded

```
FileInfo theSourceFile = new FileInfo("C:\\csharp\\testfile.txt");
            StreamReader reader = theSourceFile.OpenText();
            varii = "";

            do
            {
                text = reader.ReadLine();
                varii = varii + "," + reader.ReadLine();
                //Console.WriteLine(text); 

            } while (text != null);



            string[] split = varii.Split(new Char[] {' '});

            foreach (string s in split)
            {

                if (s.Trim() != "")
                    Console.WriteLine(s);
            }


                    int temp = split.GetUpperBound(1);
                    for (intix = 1; intix <= temp; intix++)
                    {
                        counter = 0;

                        i++;
                        ADODB.Connection cn = new ADODB.Connection();
                        ADODB.Connection cn2 = new ADODB.Connection();
                        ADODB.Recordset rs;
                        object selectfieldname;

                        //ConnectionClass conDatabase = new ADODB.Connection();

                        cn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" +
                                              "Data Source='C:\\csharp\\accident_database.mdb';";

                        rs = cn.OpenSchema(ADODB.SchemaEnum.adSchemaTables, Missing.Value, Missing.Value);


                        if (Microsoft.Vbe.Left(rs.Fields("Table_Name").Value, 4) != "MSys" && +
                            Microsoft.Vbe.Left(rs.Fields("Table_Name").Value, 4) != "Abfr")
                        {
                            strsql = "SELECT t.[" + split(intix) + "],t.fall from [" + rs.Fields("Table_Name").Value + "]" +
                                    "t Inner join 01umwelt on t.fall = [01umwelt].fall";

                        }
                        rs3 = CurrentDB.OpenRecordset(strsql);

                        while (!rs3.EOF)
                        {

                            feedbackmsg = "Processing" + rs.Fields("Table_Name").Value + "Record no:" + rs3.Fields(1).Value;
                            SysCmd acSysCmdSetStatus, feecbackmsg;
                            varii = Nz(rs3.Fields(astrfields(intix)).Value, "NullValue");

                            if (varii == "NullValue")
                            {
                                rs3.Edit();
                                rs3.Fields[astrfields(intix)].Value = 888;
                                rs3.Update();
```

I am recieving errors in the if statement

```
if (Microsoft.Vbe.Left(rs.Fields("Table_Name").Value, 4) != "MSys" && +
            Microsoft.Vbe.Left(rs.Fields("Table_Name").Value, 4) != "Abfr")
```

here Vbe.left is not getting accepted

and secondly in the sql statement following this i get an error split is an variablebut used like method.

Thanks

Comment: these errors have been solved . but now in rs.Fields i am getting an eror Error ADODB._Recordset.Fields' is a 'property' but is used like a 'method'.

Comment: it looks like there are some other places in your code where you need [] where you have (), rs3.Fields(astrfields(intix)).Value should be 
rs3.Fields[astrfields[intix]].Value

Comment: what arguments must i pass in rs3.Update();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In converting bear in mind that VBA uses the same operator () for indexes and method calls, whereas C# uses [] for indexes and () for calls to methods.

```
split(intix)
```

should be

```
split[intix]
```

Try

```
rs.Fields("Table_Name").Value.ToString().Substring(0,4), but check the length first. 

ie

rs.Fields("Table_Name").Value.ToString().Length >= 4
```

Comment: It s showing an error'string' does not contain a definition of substring

Comment: C# is case sensitive, check your method calls

Comment: sorry tksy, that was sloppy of me. Thanks Eduardo, I edited the above to reflect the correct casing for the call to Substring.

Answer (score 0):

If you add `using VB = Microsoft.VisualBasic;` namespace on top you can use `VB.Left()` instead of `Microsoft.Vbe.Left()`

Answer (score 0):

On another note:
It is really not a good idea, to create and open your connection inside the for - loop.  This is bad for performance.

You can create and open the connection to the DB outside the for loop, use the same connection during processing, and make sure you close the connection after your work is done.
Like you've implemented it now, your connection is opened / closed all the time, which is totally unnecessary in this case.