# Translating string and number comparison from VB6 to C#

Tags: c#, vba, if-statement, recordset

I have to translate some code from VB6 into C#. `rs` is a Recordset object:

```
If rs.Fields("mycolumn") < 5 Then
   myarray(Val(rs.Fields("mycolumn"))) = myarray(Val(rs.Fields("mycolumn"))) + 1".
End If
```

The problem here is comparing the column and number, because the column is a string. I already tried the VisualBasic Val()-method, but it doesn't behave totally the same?

I used this, but it doesn't give the same expression as the VB6 one. Some of the records pass thru, when they shouldn't.

```
if (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Conversion.Val(rs.Rows[k]["mycolumn"]) < 5)
{

}
```

Comment: So what should be the result of `"somestring" < 5` ? True or false ?

Comment: maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/472555/1380061

Answer (score 0):

You should convert the string to a number by using either [int.Parse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h1hf19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then you can do the comparison:

```
if(int.Parse(rs.Rows[k]["mycolumn"]) < 5) { ... }
```